# Se actualiza mas de un dato usando Linq-EF C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestion es que tengo varios arrays, donde voy a recorrer si los datos coinciden para dismunir su cantidad:

```
//DISMINUYE CANTIDAD DE CASILLER
        public void disminuyeCasiller(string[] codParte, string [] rolls, double[] cantResta)
        {
            int size = codParte.Length;

            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                string parte = codParte[i];
                string rol = rolls[i];
                double valorRes = cantResta[i];

                using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
                {
                    Casiller updateRollo = ctx.Casillers.Where(x => x.cod_parte == parte && x.rollo == rol).First();
                    double newValue = updateRollo.cantidad - valorRes;
                    updateRollo.cantidad = newValue;
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

Segun lo que hace este codigo, es saber primero de que tamaño son los arreglos (todos tendra el mismo tamaño), crea un for y obtiene la cantidad si el rollo y el codigo coinciden, a esa cantidad que recupera en este caso `300` se le restan lo que llega en `cantResta` por ejemplo `100.50`, una vez que resta lo asigna en el lugar que estaba, guarda los cambios y repite si es necesario, hasta ahi todo bien

Estoy pasando estos datos:

```
codParte=111555
rolls=RT0102
cantRest=100.50
```

al final cantidad con rollo RT0102 en la tabla me debe quedar asi: 199.50, el problema es que me actualiza ambas y queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por que me actualiza tambien `RT0103`cuando no esta siendo seleccionada esta fila? Que estoy haciendo mal en la sentencia?(me puede causar problemas con mas datos si son aun mayores)

**UPDATE**

**CAPTURA DEL BREAKPOINT**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recomendaria estructures correctamente los parametros, pasar 3 arrays es un pesima camino.

Si vas a buscar por 2 valores deberias relacionarlos en una clase, como ser:

```
public class CasillerUpdate
{
   public string codParte {get,set;}
   public string roll {get,set;}
   public string cantResta {get,set;}
}
```

entonces defines

```
public void disminuyeCasiller(List<CasillerUpdate> casillerUpdates)
{

    using(var ctx=new ModelContext())
    {
        foreach(var item in casillerUpdates)
        {
            Casiller updateRollo = ctx.Casillers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.cod_parte == item.codParte 
                                                                && x.rollo == item.roll);

            if(updateRollo == null)
                continue;

            double newValue = updateRollo.cantidad - item.cantRest;
            updateRollo.cantidad = newValue;
        }

        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Pasas una entidad por parametros y el contexto lo defines por fuera de la iteracion

Creo que algo como esto podria resolver el problema

Comment: De hecho el problema era que tenia `cod_parte` como `primary_key`, esta fue la explicación que me dieron:Una clave principal debe ser única, pero en su caso tiene más de un registro con el mismo `cod_parte.` Así que ni siquiera es una llave, y mucho menos la primaria.Cuando llama a `SaveChanges ()`, el `EF` generará una declaración SQL con una cláusula WHERE que contiene la clave principal y nada más, suponiendo que la clave primaria identificará exactamente un registro. Esa suposición es falsa, porque su "clave principal" no es realmente una clave.Solo necesitaba [key] en cod_parte y rollo.

Comment: Pudes tener claves compuestas en la entidad, pero debes mapear indicandolo https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys  como veras usarias `modelBuilder.Entity<Casiller>().HasKey(c => new { c.cod_parte, c.rollo });` asi indcarias que tiene clave compuesta